# Remote debugging an azure function's Startup in VS 2022

Tags: azure, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022, remote-debugging

I have this error in my function's app `Error configuring services in an external startup class.`

I started a remote debugging session successfully using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-azure-app-service?view=vs-2022), and is working.
The thing is everytime I re-start the app in the portal, the connection gets lost, so I am unable to reach a desired point in a Configuration method.

Is there any way to debug a startup method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can debug a startup method. by using the `Snapshot Debugger` feature in Azure Functions.

[image]

Attaching the Snapshot Debugger.

[image]

Keep the debugger point where you need to debug.
Add condition based on your requirement as shown below.

[image]

Once the debug is done you will be able to view the snapshot.

[image]

For more information, refer to [Snapshot-debugger-function-app.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/snapshot-debugger/snapshot-debugger-function-app)